# Render objects from model using the through argument

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm using the 'through' argument to connect Bot to Developer through Development team, in my html page (home.html), how would I render Developer's name in DevelopmentTeam? Also, I've tried to simply render the DevelopmentTeam name and was unsuccessful as well. I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction as I've read documentation everywhere and the issue persists.

thanks all in advance!

home.html

```
 {% for bot in bot_list_slice|slice:":5" %}
      
            <div class="col">
                <a href="{% url 'bot_detail' bot.slug %}" class="text-decoration-none">
                    <div class="row-inside-content">
                        <div class="container">
                            <img src="#">
                            <h6 class="text-dark">{{ bot.bot_name|title }}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <span class="badge bg-light text-dark">Software</span>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="container">
                            <p>{{ bot.team_members.name  **<here>** }}</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Models.py

```
class Developer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
profile = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True)

job_choices = [
    ('Backend Developer', 'Backend Developer'),
    ('Frontend Developer', 'Frontend Developer'),
    ('Lead Developer', 'Lead Developer'),
    ('Team Developer', 'Team Developer'),
    ('Designer', 'Designer'),
]
job = models.CharField(choices=job_choices, max_length=20)
team = models.ManyToManyField('DevelopmentTeam', blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super(Developer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.name)


class DevelopmentTeam (models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    members = models.ForeignKey(Developer,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    bot = models.ForeignKey("Bot", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} '.format(self.team_name, self.members, self.bot)


class Bot(models.Model):
    bot_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    company_logo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    team_members = models.ManyToManyField(Developer, through=DevelopmentTeam, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.bot_name, self.admin_approval)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.bot_name)
        super(Bot, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for members in bot.team_members.all %}}
```

I ended up changing the model, but I also realized I was doing `{{ bot.name }}` instead of `{{ members.name }}` to get the developers name in template, so I doing it wrong.